# Which Library/Components in pure Java for multi-dimensional Data exist?

Tags: java, collections, multidimensional-array, guava, olap

I am currently using Guava's [`Table`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html). In some cases I need something like:

```
Table<SomeMyKey, SomeMyKey, List<SomeMyDataClass>>
```

I am working with multi-dimensional data in Java, so it would be great to have something like a `Table`, but with more dimensions (not only rows and columns) and with collections for values. I understand that I cannot use it for a really huge amount of data, but with current amount of RAM, I think I should be able to maintain some thousands of elements...

I know about embedded Java DBs, but I do not want to have all the SQL overhead...

Comment: How do you want to work with that structure? What operations will you perform? Will smt like `Table<SomeMyKey, SomeMyKey, Table<SomeMyKey, SomeMyKey, SomeMyDataClass>>` suite your needs?

Comment: as for me, Table<SomeMyKey, SomeMyKey, Table<SomeMyKey, SomeMyKey, SomeMyDataClass>> looks more as a work around.... Now I have tree structure of my classes, where on certain levels I have simple Guava Tables. I have also a couple of big navigation Tables containing almost all my objects. I wanted to have one integrated table, with a possibility for navigation using all the demensions/breakdowns.

Comment: Perhaps, it would be better to create suiteable interface without exposing any Tables/Maps/Arrays with simple accesing by demensions method. So you can hide your complicated structure away. In this way you would not think so hard about the way to store it in ram.

Comment: Sounds like the SQL overhead would be worth it, in all honesty.

Comment: maybe... I am also thinking about object DBs..

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for an special interface to work with different dimensions of the data, like `Table` does by exposing row- and column- specific methods? I just want to make sure `ListMultimap<MyCompositeKey, SomeMyDataClass>` isn't enough, where `MyCompositeKey` just wraps a bunch of keys and implements `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Olap4J:

http://www.olap4j.org/

Also check out http://mondrian.pentaho.com/